Orange container highlights when I have dev tools enabled
When I enable dev tools, all containers start highlighting in orange, and additionally, clickable elements are highlighted in blue when hovered over. The problem does not occur when dev tools are disabled.
The problem occurs only on google chrome. It's react app and localhost, but the problem occurs on all websites in chrome.

I’ve already tried reinstalling google chrome and resetting the dev tools settings to default.
I also disabled react's dev mode.
